# Controls/Layouts of JavaFX allows to use the mouse to resize?

Tags: layout, resize, javafx-2

When I say "use the mouse to resize" I mean put the pointer at the edge, click and drag and it will be resize.
Is there any JavaFX control or layout let be do that by default?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm testing controls library in JavaFX 2 (8) and I don't remember such controls. You could implement such behavior, by setting {min/pref/max}*{width/height} on mouse DnD or mouse press/move/release event handlers.

Comment: Is there any example? I'm very interested to see a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest built-in control would be a [SplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html).

A SplitPane only has a horizontal or vertical orientation, so you couldn't arbitrarily resize in both directions unless you placed a vertical split pane inside a horizontal one (or vice versa).

Or you can create your own user resizable Pane by following Alexander Kirov's suggestion.